# Which camps are possible to pull now in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Does anyone know which neutral camps are possible to pull lane creeps into? I know that bottom-most radiant camp and I think one of the top dire camps. Are there any others? Also, can you chain the lane creeps from one camp to another and which ones? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pull both sides the small camp at the easylane 13-15 and 46-47, and also at radiant side the big camp next to the lane, at 22-3 and 53-54
And at radiant site only if you cut the trees, same time 22-23 , 52-53 when you want to pull upside,
when you play offlane and want to pull the big lane you should pull around 15-20, but its pretty easy because its they follow you pretty far from their spawn.
All these camps can stack around 53. If you pull the big camp at 53 you pull it the lane and also stack it :) gl

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising this. Does anyone have a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Additional info to @Csanesz answer:

Have a look on optional pulling with Pudge. This is useful on roam pudge or you can go on the same practice on other heroes, for example, Rubick, but it's a lot harder.

Comment: You can do similar mid pulling with Tiny's Toss. Attract the neutrals towards the lane, toss one of them onto the creep wave, then the neutral will walk back to its spawn and the creeps follow.